# Постраничная выборка начиная с определенного элемента?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Нужно сделать постраничную выборку из mysql по столбцу в котором хранится дата в формате timestamp.
Если сделать так:
'SELECT * FROM files ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0, 20'
'SELECT * FROM files ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 20, 20' и т. д.
то следующая выборка после обновления базы выведет уже полученные ранее данные.
А если так:
'SELECT * from files ORDER BY date < 1548068216 DESC LIMIT 20,20'
есть вероятность что в базе лежат данные с идентичной датой и тогда часть данных наоборот не будет получена.

Получается мне нужно:
Дорогой mysql, сделай выборку по data от большего к меньшему, найди там элемент с id (например 20) и отсчитай от него 20 элементов а результат верни мне.

Comment: а что происходит с id в пределах одинаковой даты, они идут в случайном порядке или нет ?

Comment: @Mike в случайном.

Comment: тогда у нас проблема. Только order by по уникальному ключу гарантирует точный порядок. И даже если вы найдете конкретную запись на которой остановились, то никто не сказал что новый запрос выдаст записи с той же датой в том же порядке что в предыдущий раз и значит если вы даже отсчитаете 20 записей вы не можете быть уверены, что пропустили те самые 20 записей. В общем попробую какое то решение накидать, но гарантий безошибочной работы у вас не будет никогда, пока не будет обеспечен уникальный ключ сортировки

Comment: @Mike что то мне подсказывает, что придется сортировать данные перед тем как занести их базу и делать выборку по id.
Но я был уверен, что задача тривиальная и в sql есть средства для её решения) Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы уже готовы отсчитывать записи после определенного id, значит этот id вы запомните. Предлагаю запоминать кроме id еще и дату этой записи. И тогда запрос можно будет сделать таким:

```
select *
  from (
    select files.*, @new new, @new:=(@new or id=20 or date < 1548068216) _n
      from files, (select @new:=0) x
     where date<=1548068216 order by date DESC
     limit 50
  ) y
  where new=1
 order by date DESC
 limit 20
```

Внутренний подзапрос находит все записи у которых дата меньше либо равна той, которую мы помним. Из этих записей несколько штук возможно не нужны, так как они были показаны в предыдущий раз. Поэтому мы вводим переменную @new которая будет установлена в 1 на строке с заданным id и в последующих строках сохранит свое не нулевое значение. При этом мы выводим в поле `new` значение переменной `@new` из предыдущей записи, таким образом обеспечивая задержку. За счет этого мы получим записи идущие *после* заданного id, а не начиная с него.

Что бы не напрягать БД лишней работой, внутренний подзапрос так же надо ограничить, но с запасом, что бы в него точно попали все записи с данной датой и последующие 20.

К сожалению 100% гарантии никто дать не может. В пределах одного значения даты MySQL будет выдавать записи в том порядке, как они лежат на диске (или как они перечислены в индексе). Если между двумя запросами в этой области индекса произойдут какие либо перестройки (например будут добавлены записи с такой же датой), то порядок выдачи при `order by date desc` может несколько изменится. Но думаю, что вероятностью такого события вполне можно пренебречь.

Comment: Большое спасибо!